# Spring Data Sort using comparator

Tags: hibernate, sorting, jpa, jpql, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring data JpaRepository that I use to fetch Users. I would like to know   is there a way to provide the query method with a comparator argument to sort the result. The reason I want to do this is because my result is in pages (the result needs to be sorted against all data. Sorting the entities on each page does not work for me) and the sorting predicate for the entities is loosely connected to them.
For example I have a method:

```
@Query("........")
public Page<User> findUsersByPlaceCheckInAfter(@Param("place") Place place,
        @Param("after") Date after, Pageable pageable);
```

And I would like to have something like:

```
@Query("........")
public Page<User> findUsersByPlaceCheckInAfter(@Param("place") Place place,
        @Param("after") Date after, Pageable pageable,Comparator<User> comparator);
```

If that is not possible, what are my alternatives. I am using hibernate 4.2.7.SP1 as JPA implementation.

Edit:

Detailed explanation.

Every two users in my application have a property called "matching number". 
It is calculated  as follows:

```
User A has - matchingCategories = [Books,Movies]
User B has - matchingCategories = [Books,Music]
```

User A and User B matching number is 1.

I want all the users from findUsersByPlaceCheckInAfter to be sorted by matching number. One of the users will be supplied as a parameter to the query (current loggedin user).

Comment: I know it has been a while now, but i have exactly the same problem and i can't find any solution for this. Do you have an update on the answer and can share it ?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your query itself you can provide order by clause so that whatever data you are getting will be in sorted order only.

for that you have to write comparators, better way is always getting data in sorted  order from database itself.

So that you have to write custom query which will fetch the data like
(where x.age = ?1 order by x.lastname desc)

Comment: My problem is that I want to sort the result using a predicate that is context aware (knows about the current logged in user, etc) . For example I want to sort the Users based on the number of common interests shared with the current logged in user. So I can't just do x.sth. I could probably write everything using jpql but it will become extremely ugly. I would prefer to use some of the code I already have implemented and tested.

Comment: And I don't think you can use pageable and order by together. It is either order by or sorting via the pageable parameter.

Comment: Also the property I want to sort by is computable (it is not a field/column)